# Learn joomla component / module / plugin

Tags: joomla

Hello I am very new to programming.
I want to learn very fastly joomla is there ant good way

Comment: Since you told very new to programming...........you need to be updated by Core PHP manual available at http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: Also u can read this http://www.scribd.com/doc/60530856/Joomla

Comment: In April there will be a new book released specifically about programming for Joomla. It's too early to know if it is any good, but the book is called Joomla!™ Programming. It should cover info from joomla 2.5, 1.7 and 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means u know about php.So now want to start joomla CMS>
You should read below refrences.

## About joomla CMS

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/TOC-Complete-Step-By-Step-Joomla-Programming-P625.html

## About Joomla plugin

http://learnwebdesignonline.com/tutorial-joomla-plugin

## About Joomla Template

http://www.phpeveryday.com/pack/Joomla-Template-Step-By-Step-Tutorial

## About component

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1